# MVC3 JQGrid Set colmodel dynamically from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I've seen tons of examples about setting the colmodel in the view but I haven't been able to see the controller code!
I am trying to do it but the setup keep being wrong. 
I am trying to reach this column formation:

```
colModel:
[
    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true },
    { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 100, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'Question', index: 'Question', width: 300, align: 'left' },
    { name: 'my_clickable_checkbox', index: 'my_clickable_checkbox',
        sortable: true,
        formatter: chkFmatter, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, editable: true,
        edittype: "checkbox"
    }
],
```

This is my trial in the controller:

```
return Json(
    new { colNames = new[] { "ID2", "Votes2", "Question2", "checkbox" },
          colModel = new[] { 
            new { name = "ID", index = "ID", width = 0, formatter="",
                  edittype="", hidden = true },
            new { name = "Votes", index = "Votes", width = 100, formatter="",
                  edittype="", hidden = false },
            new { name = "Question", index = "Question", width = 300, formatter="",
                  edittype="", hidden = false },
            new { name = "checkbox", index = "my_clickable_checkbox", width = 100,
                  formatter="chkFmatter", edittype="checkbox", hidden = false }
          }
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The creation of this array in the controller is forcing me to have the same number of properties in all rows. For example, I only need the `ID` to be hidden, but it forces me to supply a `hidden` property to all other columns.

Second problem, I need to call js function `chkFmatter` for the fourth column.

how can I reach that colModel formation in controller??

thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking at jqGrid [Importing and exporting](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aimport_methods) functionality. It allows you to import or export the entire jqGrid configuration to or from another file format.

You can read this blog post:

- [jqGrid and ASP.NET MVC - Configuration Import/Export](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-configuration.html)

to get the general idea on how to use those functionalities with ASP.NET MVC, but it`s a little bit out of date if it comes to ASP.NET MVC stuff (it is based on ASP.NET MVC 1).

You can also take a look at this jqGrid sample project:

- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)

which (among other things) contains sample for configuration import/export.

Most imported thing to remember here is that you still need to set any jqGrid events/callbacks or call any additional methods like 'setFrozenColumns' after configuration import.